# if iOS 6 [do this] else iOS 5 [do that]? - UIActivityViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've got a **UIActivityViewController** that shares Text and Image on Facebook/Twitter/Email, but it only works on iOS 6+.. Is it possible to pick up the iOS version running on the device and do an IF Statement to avoid crashing in iOS 5 ? If iOS6, do the following code, else do something else...?

```
-(void)shareMenu
{
    NSString *textToShare = @"Text that will be shared";
    UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"share_picture.png"];
    NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textToShare, imageToShare, nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: In general (not this specific case) I find it's usually best to use `respondsToSelector` to determine which version of a iOS class I'm dealing with, based on what methods it supports.  Among other things this helps to document the specific dependency.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if( [UIActivityViewController class] ) {
     NSString *textToShare = @"Text that will be shared";
    UIImage *imageToShare = [UIImage imageNamed:@"share_picture.png"];
    NSArray *itemsToShare = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:textToShare, imageToShare, nil];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll, UIActivityTypeMessage, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Or better use

```
if( NSClassFromString (@"UIActivityViewController") ) {

}
```

Read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/developertools/conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html)

Comment: This is a better solution than testing to iOS version numbers explicitly.

Comment: This works 100% thank you! But how do I hide the **UIBarButtonItem** in my **NavigationBar** when it is not running on iOS6? In iOS5 it is clickable but no function, so I want to hide it please? Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this, but the simplest is probably to test for the existence of this class, e.g.

```
if ([UIActivityViewController class])
  //iOS 6+
else 
  // < iOS 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [`[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIDevice/systemVersion) that will return a string for the current operating system. You can easily write a macro to see if version is at least a specified number.

Comment: This is not a good idea. It's much better to check for the existence of the desired class. It's much cleaner and direct than relying on version numbers.

Comment: There's an advantage to testing for the system version: It documents very clearly when you can actually remove the test again (i.e. when dropping iOS 5 support).